# Strange IE issues - CSS positioning incorrectly

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-9

Here is the link to the site http://kennunn.com/our_attorneys-new.html.

If you load this in Chrome you will see how it supposed to look. The problem is that IE 7-9 will load this page correctly up until it decides to do a little rearranging and it moves the attorney pics and content next to them completely out of place. I am not sure what is causing it to suddenly mess up right at the end of the page load.

We are using web fonts from fonts.com with their CSS API but I have tried removing it and it did not help.

Hopefully someone can help us out as I have been pulling my hair out over this.

Thanks for you time and efforts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue appears to be related to your script, `fixpng.js`. At a quick glance, it appears to be setting the parent node of the images to be `position:absolute`, which would naturally screw up your layout.

When I skip that code, it renders fine.

Comment: Thanks! That was indeed causing the problem!